# Grub Boot from ISO with lvm

Tags: boot, grub2, iso

In a simple boot procedure from an ISO image the below statements works well:

```
menuentry "Ubuntu.iso" {
set isofile="/iso/ubuntu.iso"
loopback loop (hd0,3)$isofile
linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz.efi boot=casper iso-scan/filename=$isofile      noeject noprompt --
initrd (loop)/casper/initrd.lz
}
```

where `hd0` is the first hdd and 3 is the partition number.

I wish how to know to do into a lvm environments

```
loopback loop (hd0,3)$isofile   ----> (hd0,???)
```

The result of blkid command is

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="28f0906e-d285-42dd-b3cd-18ef27b9261e" TYPE="ext2" 
/dev/sda5: UUID="Nx2a6F-O11u-sZxe-HDvm-6a2u-zdUf-suvn46" TYPE="LVM2_member" 
/dev/mapper/sal06--vg-root: UUID="2adef9b5-66de-4ffc-9c04-b33199815a35" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/mapper/sal06--vg-swap_1: UUID="95938380-8ee5-42c9-ad1b-eee1338870db" TYPE="swap"
```

My iso is in `/dev/mapper/sal06--vg-root`.

Answer (score 1):

Finally i found the way

just we need add to add the following line in /etc/default/grub

```
GRUB_PRELOAD_MODULES="lvm"
```

then, in /etc/grub.d/40_custom

```
menuentry "Ubuntu.iso" {
set isofile="/iso/ubuntu.iso"
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root <your LV uuid here >
loopback loop ($root)$isofile
linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz.efi boot=casper iso-scan/filename=$isofile          noeject noprompt --
initrd (loop)/casper/initrd.lz
```

}

and done, here i made a video

https://youtu.be/5MCWFStgkQU

Comment: Instead of editing two files, you can just edit one, the `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`, and add the line `insmod=lvm` as the second line. See my answer for how to boot Fedora 27 and Ubuntu 17.10 from a LVM.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by your solution and the somewhat complicated one [I found here](https://superuser.com/a/923698/180675), I used the following, which works for loading a Fedora 27 KDE iso and a Ubuntu 17.10 iso.

I just appended the following lines in the file `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`

```
menuentry "Live Fedora KDE 27" --class fedora {
  insmod part_msdos
  insmod lvm
  set iso_path="/erik/Downloads/transmission/Fedora-KDE-Live-x86_64-27/Fedora-KDE-Live-x86_64-27-1.6.iso"
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 6340d364-fc09-44d1-914f-b902a6394a55
  loopback loop ($root)$iso_path
  linux (loop)/isolinux/vmlinuz iso-scan/filename=${iso_path} root=live:CDLABEL=Fedora-KDE-Live-27-1-6 rootfstype=auto rd.live.image quiet
  initrd (loop)/isolinux/initrd.img
}

menuentry "Ubuntu 17.10.1" --class ubuntu {
  insmod part_msdos
  insmod lvm
  set iso_path="/erik/Downloads/transmission/ubuntu-17.10.1-desktop-amd64.iso"
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 6340d364-fc09-44d1-914f-b902a6394a55
  loopback loop ($root)$iso_path
  linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz.efi  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper iso-scan/filename=${iso_path} quiet splash ---
  initrd (loop)/casper/initrd.lz
}
```

### Explanation

- The line that begins with `set iso_path` defines the path, where the iso file can be found on the logical volume. When I start my system, it lies in `/home/erik/Downloads/transmission/Fedora-KDE-Live-x86_64-27/Fedora-KDE-Live-x86_64-27-1.6.iso"`, but `/home` is the mounted logical volume, so I leave this out and begin the path with `/erik/Downloads/…`
- The line that begins with `search` has a strange alphanumerical variable (a so called UUID) at the end, that begins with `6340`. I got this number from the command

  ```
  sudo blkid
  ```

  which gave me, along others, the following line

  ```
  /dev/mapper/fedora_pluto-home: UUID="6340d364-fc09-44d1-914f-b902a6394a55" TYPE="ext4"
  ```
- Then, another important thing if you want to boot other iso files, are the lines that begin with `linux` and `initrd`. I got them by **opening the iso file** with `file-roller` (gui for extracting compressed archives) or `mc` (console file manager).

  - **Fedora and similar:** There you go to the directory `/isolinux`, where you will find a file called `isolinux.cfg`. There I found some lines beginning with `label`, and below them the following important lines

    ```
    kernel vmlinuz
    append initrd=initrd.img root=live:CDLABEL=Fedora-KDE-Live-27-1-6 rd.live.image quiet
    ```

    which you will use to fill the last two lines of my grub2 `menuentry`.
  - **Ubuntu and similar:** There you go to the directory `/boot/grub`, where you will find a file called `grub.cfg`. Here you will find some lines beginning with `menuentry`, and below them the following important lines

    ```
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz.efi  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper quiet splash ---
    initrd  /casper/initrd.lz
    ```

    which you can just copy.